# Using copy constructor and operator overload - 'pointer being freed was not allocated'

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I've created a class called `MyInteger`, and I'm trying to create a copy constructor that will correctly make a separate copy of the memory `pInteger` points to, and make `pInteger` in the new object point to it.  I need to overload the `=` operator so that each of the two objects involved has its own separate copy of the memory that its own `pInteger` points to.

`MyInteger` specification:

```
class MyInteger {
public:
    MyInteger(int);
    MyInteger(MyInteger &);
    ~MyInteger();
    int getMyInt();
    void setMyInt(int);
    MyInteger operator=(MyInteger&);

private:
    int * pInteger;

};
```

`MyInteger` implementation:

```
MyInteger::MyInteger(int i) {
    pInteger = new int;
    *pInteger = i;
}


MyInteger::MyInteger(MyInteger &obj) {
    pInteger = new int;
    pInteger = obj.pInteger;
}

MyInteger MyInteger::operator=(MyInteger &i) {
    pInteger = new int;
    pInteger = i.pInteger;

    return i;
}


MyInteger::~MyInteger() {
    delete pInteger;
}

int MyInteger::getMyInt() {
    return *pInteger;
}

void MyInteger::setMyInt(int i) {
    pInteger = new int;
    *pInteger = i;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is at least partially due to the fact that I'm reassigning `pInteger` in the constructor and operator overload: `pInteger = new int;` and then `pInteger = obj.pInteger;`.  I think the second assignment is nullifying the first assignment using `new`, so I'm getting

> pointer being freed was not allocated

because `pInteger` was not correctly being dynamically allocated.  Am I going in the right direction here?  I'm not sure how to fix this, any help would be great.

Comment: Your copy-constructo and assignment-operator are both wrong. Look more closely, you write `pInteger =` and then `pInteger =` again on the second line - that will overwrite what you did on the first line.   You did it right in the `int` constructor, so look at that and then apply the same idea to your other functions. The `setMyInt` function and the assignment operator leaks memory, you should only call `new` in the constructors. Also , the assignment operator should return `*this` and have a reference as the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyInteger::MyInteger(MyInteger &obj) {
    pInteger = new int;
    pInteger = obj.pInteger;
}

MyInteger MyInteger::operator=(MyInteger &i) {
    pInteger = new int;
    pInteger = i.pInteger;

    return i;
}
```

You assign `pInteger` the correct value -- pointing to a newly-allocated integer. Then you immediately overwrite it with the wrong value -- a pointer to an integer owned by another object.

Also, your `operator=` returns a copy. You'd expect `(j = i)++;` to modify `j`, not a temporary.

Comment: I realize the second line is wrong, but I'm not sure what to do to make `pInteger` in the new object point to a copy of the memory the original `pInteger` points to?

Comment: @123 `*pInteger = *i.pInteger;`

Comment: Or just replace both lines with `pInteger = new int (i.getMyInt());`